# What are "full size" piano keys?

Tags: piano

Is there an official measurement in terms of key width for what can be described as full size keys? Or does it vary between pianos - if so are there rough rules?

Answer (score 0):

It varies between (upright) pianos and other keyboard instruments (which are mostly smaller) but is rather standardized for grand pianos.